# Error by trying to use JDBC authentication in Spring Security

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to use JDBC authentication from Spring Security to authenticate a user in a simple web project. In this project I'm using Java with Spring boot and Spring Security, Thymeleaf and Bootstrap. Here I have the following configurations:

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.each.bd2</groupId>
    <artifactId>PetDonation</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>PetDonation</name>
    <description>Web application that help people to donate and/or adopt pets</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Class that configure the project security:

```
package com.each.bd2.PetDonation.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
        httpSecurity
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/home/**", "/usuario/novo")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                    .formLogin(form -> form
                        .loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/usuario/home", true)
                        .permitAll())
                .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
            .passwordEncoder(encoder)
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, enabled from users where username=?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, authority from authorities where username=?");
    }
}
```

Users class (Here, my username is an email):

```
package com.each.bd2.PetDonation.config;

import com.each.bd2.PetDonation.entities.Usuario;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @NotBlank
    private String username;
    @NotBlank
    private String password;
    private boolean enabled;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "authorities", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "username"))
    //@OneToMany(mappedBy = "users")
    private Set<Authorities> authorities = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Usuario usuario;

    public Users() {
    }

    public Users(String username, String password, boolean enabled) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public Set<Authorities> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    public void addAuthority(String authority) {
        this.authorities.add(new Authorities(authority));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Users that = (Users) o;
        return username.equals(that.username) && password.equals(that.password);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(username, password);
    }
}
```

Authorities class:

```
package com.each.bd2.PetDonation.config;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

@Embeddable
public class Authorities{

    private String authority;

    public Authorities() {}

    public Authorities(String authority) {
        this.authority = authority;
    }

}
```

Login controller:

```
package com.each.bd2.PetDonation.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @GetMapping
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login(){
        return "login";
    }
}
```

Login HTML:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<head></head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <h1>Entrar</h1>
        <div class="card row justify-content-center align-items-center mb-3 ml-4">
            <form th:action="@{/login}" class="card-body" method="post">
                <div class="form-group mb-3 col-5">
                    <label for="username">Email</label>
                    <input name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="email"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mb-3 col-5">
                    <label for="password">Senha</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="senha"/>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-success justify-content-center" type="submit">Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I also have a registration class that I'm sure is working, because in my database I have the following example of an insert user (I'm using BCryptPasswordEncoder to encode my password):
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DC6rh.png)

Ok, after all of this. When I try to authenticate myself, I recieve the following:
[login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijUpN.png)

EDIT 1:

Here you can find the repository with the whole project: https://github.com/marco-fpereira/pet-donation/tree/master

Here is the spring security debbuging log resulting of an attempt of login: (Sorry, I can't paste the image directly here)

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqWb2.jpg) [img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj8Nu.jpg) [img3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJAqV.jpg)

Comment: Yes, it exists. 

To be easier to help me, here you can find the repository with the whole project: 
https://github.com/marco-fpereira/pet-donation/tree/master

Comment: The second log file says that your user has no authorities and is handled as not found. So add roles to your user in your database.

Comment: Thank you, after I added what you told me, it worked!